# Netty 4.0 Difference between ChannelInboundByteHandler and ChannelInboundMessageHandler

Tags: handler, netty, channel

In Netty 4.0, What is the difference between ChannelInboundByteHandler and ChannelInboundMessageHandler or ChannelOutboundByteHandler and ChannelOutboundMessageHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Channel*ByteHandler operates on a "stream" of bytes and Channel*MessageHandler on messages.

Also read [1].

[1] http://netty.io/4.0/guide/

Comment: thank you, I know that, but i can convert messages into bytes and i wonder what the difference is?